# ways to speed up .txt to db in django

Tags: python, django

I have a text file like this:

```
AN  AD  Aixas
AN  AD  Aixirivall
AN  AD  Aixovall
AN  AD  Ansalonga
```

And I want to import this text file to the database.
I am doing it like this.

```
fips_codes = []
        iso_codes = []
        city_names = []

        for line in city_file.readlines():
            cc_fips = line[:2]
            cc_iso = line[3:5]
            name = line[6:]

            fips_codes.append(cc_fips)
            iso_codes.append(cc_iso)
            city_names.append(name)

        counter = 0
        for item in fips_codes:
            country = Country.objects.get(cc_fips=fips_codes[counter], cc_iso=iso_codes[counter])
            city_object = City(country=country, name=city_names[counter])
            city_object.save()
            counter = counter + 1
```

is there any way to speed up this process?

Comment: If the performance is most important and you are using postgres, you can store the whole file into database temporary table and then create cities with one raw sql.
More pythonian way, create dict with all countries, then create cities (all at once or in chunks) with bulk_create.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop twice

```
for line in city_file.readlines():
    fips, iso, name = line.split()
    country = Country.objects.get(cc_fips=fips, cc_iso=iso)
    City.objects.create(country=country, name=name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to limit database calls. The number of countries is relatively small, so you can load all countries at once and make a map from fips/iso codes to country ids:

```
countries = {
    (c.cc_fips, c.cc_iso): c.id
    for c in Country.objects.all()
}
```

Then create cities in bulk:

```
cities = []
for line in city_file.readlines():
    fips, iso, name = line.split()
    cities.append(
        City(country_id=countries[(fips, iso)], name=name)
    )
City.objects.bulk_create(cities)
```

If the number of cities is very large, you can save cities in chunks, e.g. every 100 cities, for not to hold in memory all city objects.